# Regex in Linq (EntityFramework), String processing in database

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq, entity-framework

I have a column in my table which contains values as

```
    "FilterA:123,234,34;FilterB:12,23;FilterC:;FilterD:45;"
```

Filters are separated by ';' and the values of each filter are separated by ','. There is a ':' in between a Filter's name and it's values.

Now, can I do anything which could fetch out the values part only? Like "123,234,34" for "FilterA". Or can I give it a number like "234" to search in the value part of "FilterA" and/or "54" in the value part of "FilterB"? I know it is possible with using regex, i guess, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Do you want to find some rows based on a filter's value or do you want to extract the filter values from some already selected rows?

Comment: I want to select some rows comparing my data with the data in the filter string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use regular expressions in Linq to Entities queries, because they cannot be translated into SQL. You even can't use `String.Split` to split your filters by `;`. You have two options here:

- Change database table structure. E.g. create table `Foo_Filter` which will link your entities to filters. And then create table `Filters` which will contain filters data.
- Execute query in memory and use Linq to Objects. This option will be slow, because you have to fetch all data from database to memory

Comment: "Execute query in memory and use Linq to Objects. This option will be slow, because you have to fetch all data from database to memory" this is what i have been trying to avoid!

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui then only first option left for you. There is no way to fetch FilterA data from string with Linq to Entities

Comment: EF is such a complicating and limiting pile of s....

Answer (score 5):

If your underlying database provider is SQL Server then you could make use of [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) to filter the database result set down to a manageable subset of data that can then be analysed locally with RegEx

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @lazyberezovsky, you can't do regex in Linq to Entities because it can't translate that into SQL.  You could pull all records back into memory then do Linq to Objects on it (do a `.ToList()` to a variable then a second linq query for this regex) but that means you'll load every db record into memory to process this query.  Same recomendations: change the DB structure such that you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you wanted everything to execute on the database server you'd need a SQL function that could parse these filters, perhaps returning a multi-column table. Unfortunately I am not on a machine where I could provide any sample code.