# Return Values That Are In Lowercase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

We recently discovered a bug in our system whereby any serial numbers that have been entered in lowercase have not been processed correctly.

To correct this, we need to add a one off function that will run through the database and re-process all items with lower case serial numbers.

In linq, is there a query I can run that will return a list of such items?

Note: I am not asking how to convert lowercase to uppercase or reverse, which is all google will return. I need to generate a list of all database entries where the serial number has been entered in lowercase.

EDIT: I am using Linq to MS SQL, which appears to be case insensitive.

Comment: What have you tried?  Post the code you have

Comment: You do not show how your serial numbers look, you do not show how your EF is constructed, you do not show what you tried. How should we be able to help? My crystal ball is out of order. You also did not tell us how big of a problem that is - 1000 serial numbers? A million? More? You can try something simple as `serialNo.Where(s => s == s.ToLower()` on it if there are few. You can check for Any() and if one is lower others might be as well. If its a oneoff-job, it might not even be performant at all. Just a graball on Sql and store in temp table could be enough to isolate them.

Comment: At the point of posting I hadn't tried anything, as I don't even know where to begin with this. I've since tried s == s.ToLower(), however linq / SQL Server is case insensitive, and so returns all serials, not just the lowercase ones.

This is a one off job, so performance is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can try something like this:

```
var result = serialnumber.Any(c => char.IsLower(c));
```

**[EDIT]**

Well, in case of Linq to Entities...

As is stated here: [Regex in Linq (EntityFramework), String processing in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417947/regex-in-linq-entityframework-string-processing-in-database), there's few ways to workaround it.

> - Change database table structure. E.g. create table Foo_Filter which will link your entities to filters. And then create table Filters
>     which will contain filters data.
> - Execute query in memory and use [Linq to Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx). This option will be slow, because you have to fetch all data from database to memory

Note: link to MSDN documentation has been added by me.

For example:

```
var result = context.Serials.ToList().Where(sn => sn.Any(c => char.IsLower(c)));
```

Another way is to use [SqlMethods.Like Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx)

Finally, i'd strongly recommend to read this: [Case sensitive search using Entity Framework and Custom Annotation](https://milinaudara.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/case-sensitive-search-using-entity-framework-with-custom-annotation/)

Comment: Not the downvoter - but I am not suggesting anyhing because the Q is very unclear on any details. Probably the reason someone dv.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, if it's the reason of of down-vote, i feel sad.

Comment: Me too, your advice is sound. But its an -yet- ill formed questions, hence I wont upvote your answer neither ;) typically the answers to such questions bite you in the .... b/c the get refined and refined and end up smth completely other then you thought.

Comment: @MaciejLos - this on paper looks like its the ideal solution, however it doesn't appear to work with linq to entities. Sorry, i should have specified that

Comment: @GavinCoates, SQL provides a way to detect lower case. `WHERE SerialNumber Like '%[a-z]%'`

Comment: @GavinCoates, I've found very interesting article about that. See: [Case sensitive search using Entity Framework and Custom Annotation](https://milinaudara.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/case-sensitive-search-using-entity-framework-with-custom-annotation/)