# Filter two arrays in LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, compare

I have a list:

```
List<string> userGroups;
```

userGroups has elements something like this:

```
"Electronic"
"Mechanical"
"Computer"
```

and a query:

```
IQueryable<UserRole> userRoles = Query(); //fetched from DB
```

userRoles has elements something like this:

| GroupName | AliasName |
| --- | --- |
| Electronic,Computer,Science | ELC |
| Mechanical,Hardware | MC |

Now I want to have functionality something like this:

If any of the elements in "**userGroup**" matches with the **GroupName** of the table I should select that row from the table. Note that **GroupName** contains **comma** separated values which needs to be checked against **userGroup** elements.

If the GroupName is not a comma separated value then following code would work:

```
userRoles = userRoles.Where(r => userGroups.Contains(r.GroupName));
```

I want something like this:

```
userRoles = userRoles.Where(r => userGroups.Intersect(r.GroupName.Split(",").ToList()).Any());
```

But unfortunately the above code will not work!

I can achieve this functionality by foreach but I don't want to do it in-memory operation rather I prefer deferred execution, most likely using linq.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex in Linq (EntityFramework), String processing in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417947/regex-in-linq-entityframework-string-processing-in-database)

Comment: Any(r => userGroups.Contains(r.GroupName)).Select() might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want

```cs
userRoles = userRoles.Where(x => x.GroupName.Split(',').Any(userGroups.Contains));
```

It will keep all those `UserRole`s whose `GroupName`s contains at least one of the elements in `userGroups`.

Comment: The problem is that `userRoles` is an `IQueryable` and the OP wants to do deferred execution rather than materializing the collection and performing an in-memory operation. So, this won't work.

Comment: @41686d6564 I read it as they already fetched the data and have it in memory, and just want the laziness of linq